# Django set Boolean to False when clicking a button

Tags: python, django

The following code (just to learn Django) allows to mark the user's ticket as "Solved" with an HTML button. When the button is clicked, ticked_solved is set to True, ticket_waiting is set to False.

This is also recognized in the template, which I have tested. But then in the dashboard the object would have to change to False/True as well, which as you can see in the screenshot is not the case.

I do all this with a form, which is probably not the smartest option either.

\\ models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    ticket_waiting = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ticket_solved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

\\forms.py

```
class TicketSolved(forms.Form):
    delete = forms.CharField(
        label='', max_length=0).widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

\\views.py

```
def ticket_system_view(request, id):
    obj = Ticket.objects.get(id=id)

    form2 = TicketSolved(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form2.is_valid():
            obj.ticket_waiting = False
            obj.ticket_solved = True

    return render(request, 'ticket-system.html', {'obj': obj, 'form2': form2})
```

\\ .html

```
{% if obj.user != request.user %}
<p>Page Not Found</p>

{% else %}
<p>Ticket ID {{obj.id}}</p>

{{ obj.title }} {{ obj.description }} {% endif %}
<br></br>

<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form2 }}
  <button type="submit">Status to Solved</button>
</form>

----Just to test if it works:

 {% if obj.ticket_waiting == True %}
  <p>Waiting for Reply.</p>
  {% else %}
  <p>Ticket solved.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

\\urls.py if needed

```
    path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

And  a screenshot how it looks after clicking the button
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQlhL.png)

Do you know why in the admin dashboard the checkboxes don't adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to save the object after updating:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def ticket_system_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.ticket_waiting = False
        obj.ticket_solved = True
        obj.save()  # 🖘 save the update in the database
        return redirect('view_ticket', id=id)

    return render(request, 'ticket-system.html', {'obj': obj})
```

You don't need any form here: this is a simple button, you can render a form with only a button that looks like:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">Status to Solved</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.